# How do I pass a function from a ViewModel to my scaffold's floating action button in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: mvvm, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt, android-jetpack-compose-scaffold

I'm building an Android app using purely Jetpack Compose. My entire application is wrapped under one scaffold, and has a ViewModel for each "screen" (which are composables) in my app. Because of that, I have some conditional statements in my scaffold to determine the floating action button (FAB) based on the route. However, one of the FABs needs access to a function in a ViewModel, which is only created when I navigate to the route that holds that composable, and I'm at a loss on the best way to give the FAB access to that viewmodel function.

Take the following example (based off my code), and note the FAB for the route "route3".

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            MyApp()
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun MyApp() {
        val navController = rememberNavController()
        val backstackEntry = navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
        val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()

        Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
            Scaffold(
                topBar = { ... },
                bottomBar = { ... },
                floatingActionButton = {
                    when (backstackEntry.value?.destination?.route) {
                        "route2" -> FAB2(navController)
                        "route3" -> FAB3(navController) // Needs to access function from viewModel3
                    }
                },
                scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
            ) {
                MyNavHost(navController, scaffoldState)
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun MyNavHost(navController: NavHostController, scaffoldState: ScaffoldState) {
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = "route1"
        ) {
            composable("route1") { Destination1() }
            composable("route2") { Destination2() }
            composable("route3") { Destination3() }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun Destination1() { ...}

    @Composable
    fun Destination2() { ... }

    @Composable
    fun Destination3() {
        val viewModel3: CustomViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        Screen3(viewModel3)
    }

}
```

So my main question is, if the `FAB3` variable needs to access a function from `viewModel3`, how would I go about doing it?

Comment: Same problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to just switch over to using a scaffold for every screen.

Honestly, this makes managing routes a lot easier, because in the single scaffold scenario, it was getting difficult managing all of the possible routes for things like the TopBar and FAB in large `when()` blocks.

But if anyone has a solution to the original question that would be appreciated!

Comment: Consider the solution provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71186641/how-to-control-a-scaffolds-floatingactionbutton-onclick-from-child-composable That's basically the same way it's done on e.g. `ReactJS` applications which also use a declarative UI.

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf Thanks for linking that! That solution does answer my original question and I urge people to take a look if they landed here first. However, that solution doesn't work for me because I want to keep track of extra things: 1. Different FAB icons for different screens. 2. I also have a FAB that de-extends itself when a LazyGrid has scrolled past a certain point, so that's something else to keep track of. So unless storing a Composable in state (if possible), keeping track of those other states would be difficult. Thus, using a scaffold per screen is still the best solution for me.

Comment: how did it go with your solution, especially, do you use a NavigationBar (BottomNavigationBar)? Wouldn't having a new one on each screen interrupt the touch animations when the new screen is rendered?